# Font size for footer, in jsPDF autoTable

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

So,

I've successfully modified everything else but can't figure how to change just the footers font size, it is now way too big compared to table font itself.

```
    let pdf = new jsPDF({orientation: 'l'});
    let res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('capture'));
    const totalPagesExp = '{total_pages_count_string}';
    let height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    const footer = function(res) {
        let str = 'Sivu ' + res.pageCount;

        if (typeof pdf.putTotalPages === 'function') {
            str = str + ' / ' + totalPagesExp;
            str = str + ' -- ' + moment().format('L').toString();
        }

        //PROBLEM GOES HERE
        pdf.text(str, 5, height - 5, {
            fontSize: 5
        });
    };

    pdf.autoTable(
        res.columns,
        res.data,
        {margin: {top: 25, bottom: 15},
        styles: {overflow: 'linebreak',
                fontSize: 6},
        showHeader: 'everyPage',
        afterPageContent: footer,
        theme: 'plain'});

    if (typeof pdf.putTotalPages === 'function') {
        pdf.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
    }

    pdf.save( 'file.pdf');
```

Footer itself is iterating nicely, page numbers show up as they are suppose to, but even if i pass options object into `psd.text()` as stated in documentation, it still wont change the font size.

[Documentation for text](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pdf.setFontSize(5);
```

and remember to put it *before* putting the text into footer,

```
        pdf.setFontSize(5);
        pdf.text(str, 5, height - 5, {
            styles: { fontSize: 5 },
        });
```